# MVC design patttern

Tags: model-view-controller

I have created a system which is similar to the following:

[image: Diagram of my system]

Here, GUIController and DataCollection classes act as controller classes. Does it violates the MVC design pattern? Do I have to make GUIController the only controller? (Here View is not keeping any instance of DataCollection)

Answer (score 1):

MVC can have multiple controllers.

But does DataCollection really act as a controller in this case? I get the impression from your diagram that it is more like a model because it administers the data.

The responsibility of a controller is to analyse and execute user input